# Python & Pandas: Combine columns into a date

Tags: python, pandas

In my `dataframe`, the time is separated in 3 columns: `year`, `month`, `day`, like this:
[image]

How can I convert them into `date`, so I can do time series analysis?

I can do this:

```
df.apply(lambda x:'%s %s %s' % (x['year'],x['month'], x['day']),axis=1)
```

which gives:

```
1095       1954 1 1
1096       1954 1 2
1097       1954 1 3
1098       1954 1 4
1099       1954 1 5
1100       1954 1 6
1101       1954 1 7
1102       1954 1 8
1103       1954 1 9
1104      1954 1 10
1105      1954 1 11
1106      1954 1 12
1107      1954 1 13
```

But what follows?

**EDIT:**
This is what I end up with:

```
from datetime import datetime
df['date']= df.apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime("{0} {1} {2}".format(x['year'],x['month'], x['day']), "%Y %m %d"),axis=1)
df.index= df['date']
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how to convert value to time:

```
import datetime


df.apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime("{0} {1} {2} 00:00:00".format(x['year'],x['month'], x['day']), "%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S"),axis=1)
```

Comment: It gives me `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`, what the problem?

Comment: It was missing your lambda expression variable used from the dataframe. i still feel like this is forced but let me know if it works.

Comment: I think maybe we should convert into `datetime`, not `time`?

Comment: Change to datetime. Better?

Comment: this works for me:
df.apply(lambda x: pandas.datetime.strptime("{0} {1} {2} 00:00:00".format(x['year'],x['month'], x['day']), "%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S"),axis=1)

Comment: Really? This code is taking each line, formatting a date string, and reparsing it right away. Why not just use the `datetime` constructor?

Answer (score 4):

It makes no sense to format a date to a string and immediately reparse it; use the `datetime` constructor instead:

```
df.apply(lambda x: datetime.date(x['year'], x['month'], x['day']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler and much faster way to convert 3 columns with year, month and day to a single datetime column in pandas:

```py
import pandas

pandas.to_datetime(df)
```

Besides the code being much simpler than the accepted answer, in my computer your implementation takes 22.3 seconds, while this one takes 175 milliseconds, with a 1 million rows dataframe. **This implementation is 127x faster**.

Note that in your case, the columns are already named `year`, `month` and `day`, which is a requirement for the input dateframe of `to_datetime`. If they have different names, you need to rename them first (e.g. `df.rename(columns={'<your_year_col>': 'year', ...})`).