# How to join pandas Series of numbers to make it one number

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm using Pandas library.

I have three columns in dataset named 'hours', 'minutes' and 'seconds'
[image: the picture shows the three columns]

I want to join the three columns to make it in time format.

For e.g the first column should read as 9:33:09

How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869257/python-pandas-combine-columns-into-a-date Shows a similar Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to timedelta and add -

```
pd.to_timedelta(df["hours"], unit='h') + pd.to_timedelta(df["minutes"], unit='m') + pd.to_timedelta(df["sec"], unit='S')
```

Viewing you example, I think that the `sec` column is actually microseconds, if that's the case use -

```
pd.to_timedelta(df["hours"], unit='h') + pd.to_timedelta(df["minutes"], unit='m') + pd.to_timedelta(df["sec"], unit='us')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string operations and pandas for this.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read csv

data=pd.read_csv("data.csv")


# Create a DataFrame object

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["hour","mins","sec"])


# Iterate through records and print the values.

for ind in df.index: 
  hour=str(df['hour'][ind])
  min=str(df['mins'][ind])
  sec=str(df['sec'][ind])

  sec=sec[:len(sec)-4]

  if(len(sec)==1):
    sec="0"+sec

  print(hour+":"+min+":"+sec)
```

Output:
`HH:MM:SS`

It appends 0 if seconds are of 1 digit.